# Is it possible to fetch part of a remote image in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to extract EXIF data from remote images using Javascript. It works OK at the moment but it gets quite slow when the image is large since I download the entire image before extracting the EXIF data.

EXIF data is always within the first 128kb of an image (I believe) so I really don't need the entire image.

Is it possible to somehow only fetch the first XXX kb of a remote file with JS?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal: Actually, you can.  See the `Range:` header.

Comment: Instead, you can extract that information ahead of time, maybe save it in your database. This way you have that information available

Comment: Hey good to know. I didnt know about all of these. Great that you guys helped me understand the same

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [range request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#range-request-header) works just fine:

```
$.ajax({ // assuming that you use jQuery
    url: 'http://example.com/images/001.jpg',
    headers: {
        range: 'bytes=0-131071' // inclusive
    },
    complete: function (xhr) {
        var data = xhr.responseText;
        console.log(data.length); // 131072
        console.log(xhr.status); // 206
        yourExifParser(data);
    }
});
```

Online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9CknY/1/

But [same-origin-policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) applies.